# How do I manually import the clamav virus definition file?

Tags: clamav

I would like to manually download the main.cvd for clamav and then import it from a local location. I see this is possible using clamav-clamfresh if I configure it to use `DatabaseMirror machine1.example.com` but that requires running an http webserver on port 80 of machine1.example.com which I don't want to do.

If I get the main.cvd file onto a machine is there some way to manually trigger the import?

Comment: I got an answer at http://lists.clamav.net/pipermail/clamav-users/2018-June/006273.html that is more complete. It notes that if using clamd daemon then it *can* be reloaded using `clamdscan –reload` but it doesn't need to be reloaded because it will get reloaded as often as SelfCheck in clamd.conf says to look at it. I don't want to answer my own question, but neither of the below really answers the question I asked.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could probably do a script like so to download the updated file then copy it over to the proper location for an update manually.

**Script contents**

```
#!/bin/bash
wget http://database.clamav.net/main.cvd
sudo cp main.cvd /var/lib/clamav/
sudo chown clamav:clamav /var/lib/clamav/main.cvd
sudo chmod 644 /var/lib/clamav/main.cvd
```

Comment: Is any further step necessary to get clamav and clamd to recognize the main.cvd file has been placed into that location?

Comment: I don't believe so.  When it downloads the file it drops it into that folder then the applications look there when they run.

Answer (score 11):

If clamav have been installed from official repositories, the database folder is **`/var/lib/clamav`**
This folder contains some files, **not only `main.cvd`**
3 files are part of the database:
https://database.clamav.net/main.cvd
https://database.clamav.net/daily.cvd
https://database.clamav.net/bytecode.cvd

Once a machine1 have his ClamAV updated with freshclam (or so), another machine2 can **copy the directory content** to his local `/var/lib/clamav` folder.
To **check if** manual update of machine2 has **worked**, you can compare the outputs of **`clamscan --version`** on machine1 and machine2. And/or compare `md5sum` of `.cvd` files.

This could be pretty easy to script with some backup and rollback actions in case of failure.
Of course, the embedded [Private Local Mirror](https://www.clamav.net/documents/private-local-mirrors) feature seems more elegant but require a local webserver.

Answer (score 2):

[Change the User-Agent to something unique](https://github.com/Cisco-Talos/cvdupdate/commit/d00f81545ed48b4a6aad8eb4fb5da90fc517e65b)

`wget --user-agent='CVDUPDATE/0 (43fde49b-905f-43c6-a51b-e1324cd23280)' https://database.clamav.net/main.cvd https://database.clamav.net/daily.cvd https://database.clamav.net/bytecode.cvd`

Comment: This seems like it might solve a different problem with similar symptoms or perhaps something else. I am glad to hear about the idea of using a unique user agent, though not sure how likely folks are to do that.