# How to offline update ClamAV database?

Tags: clamav, clamtk

I did download  [ClamAv datebase](https://database.clamav.net/daily.cvd) and I want to offline update the signature database, as far as I surfed I could not find a solution and also in ClamTK, ClamAVs GUI there is no option for the offline update, I am using the latest update of Ubuntu.
Thank you in advance for helping me.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1046700/how-do-i-manually-import-the-clamav-virus-definition-file)? I've not tried it, but that looks about right.

Comment: Is that not what freshclam and /etc/freshclam.conf is for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Download the file definitions from the ClamAV site:

```
wget http://db.local.clamav.net/main.cvd
wget ​​http://db.local.clamav.net/daily.cvd
```

The two files are required

Copy these files into the ClamAV directory:

```
cd ~/Downloads
sudo mv daily.cvd main.cvd /var/lib/clamav
```

This will overwrite the old definition files